# Is there a way to make this function fast and concise?

Tags: python

I want to combine these two loops into one, but I'm concerned t would be slower if it had to check the boolean `is_fahrenheit` in every iteration.

```
if is_fahrenheit:
    for c in cities_list:
        degree_fahrenheit = round((c.degrees - 273.15) * (9/5) + 32)
        weather_info = {'id': c.id, 'city': c.name, 'degrees': degree_fahrenheit, 'state': c.state, 'time_of_day': c.time_of_day}
        cities_info.append(weather_info)
else:
    for c in cities_list:
        degree_celsius = round(c.degrees - 273.15)
        weather_info = {'id': c.id, 'city': c.name, 'degrees': degree_celsius, 'state': c.state, 'time_of_day': c.time_of_day}
        cities_info.append(weather_info)
```

How can I best do this?

Comment: Yes but most likely it's irrelevant for the general speed of the whole application.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." Remember that. Don't optimize until you have to. Just try to write pretty code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be marginally slower but generally irrelevant unless your `cities_list` was *massive,* and you'll probably find better optimisations elsewhere.

Any question as to whether something could be made faster needs a way to ensure that it *needs* to be made faster (one of my mantras is "measure, don't guess"). There's very little point doubling the speed of something that takes 10 nanoseconds, for example. Well, unless you need to do it more than 100,000,000 times per second :-)

So, unless your lists are *truly* large, just check the flag within the loop, it will most likely not be an appreciable impact. But, as a general rule for clean code, try to minimise the scope where the choices apply, such as with:

```py
for c in cities_list:
    if is_fahrenheit:
        degrees = round((c.degrees - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32)
    else:
        degrees = round(c.degrees - 273.15)

    weather_info = {'id': c.id, 'city': c.name, 'degrees': degrees,
        'state': c.state, 'time_of_day': c.time_of_day}

    cities_info.append(weather_info)
```

Comment: Even though `cities_list` is massive, it still consume a little time if it's built-in list. There isn't necessary to optimize it.

Comment: @yixuan: unless performance is *measured,* one can't really say for sure. In any case, whether optimisation is required is a product of both the current performance *and* the required performance. For example, you may think something taking only a millisecond would be fine but, if you need to do it 10,000 times per second, it needs optimising, plain and simple.

Answer (score 0):

How about just:

```
for c in cities_list:
    degree_celsius = c.degrees - 273.15
    degrees = degree_celsius * (9/5) + 32 if is_fahrenheit else degree_celsius
    weather_info = {'id': c.id, 'city': c.name, 'degrees': round(degrees), 'state': c.state, 'time_of_day': c.time_of_day}
    cities_info.append(weather_info)
```

If you are really worried about performance of adding an if statement for each city, you could do something like this:

```
if is_fahrenheit:
    multiplier = (9/5)
    adder = 32
else:
    multiplier = 1.0
    adder = 0 

for c in cities_list:
    temp_celsius = c.degrees - 273.15
    temp = round(temp_celsisus * multiplier + adder)
    weather_info = {'id': c.id, 'city': c.name, 'degrees': temp, 'state': c.state, 'time_of_day': c.time_of_day}
    cities_info.append(weather_info)
```

However, if it's really performance critical it probably should not be done in python -- e.g. you could push the performance critical pieces to Cython or the like, see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips) for related tips

Comment: I did consider that second case but the useless `* 1 + 0` is probably *more* expensive than a boolean check :-)

Comment: yes, that's fair it probably is significantly more expensive in the celsius case

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems it is premature optimization, you can use `dict`

```py
d = {True: lambda x: round((x - 273.15) * (9/5) + 32),
    False: lambda x: round(x - 273.15)}

for c in cities_list:
    degree_ = d[is_fahrenheit](c.degrees)
    weather_info = {'id': c.id, 'city': c.name, 'degrees': degree_, 'state': c.state, 'time_of_day': c.time_of_day}
    cities_info.append(weather_info)
```